# Laravel Eloquent PHP how to get all rows in MySQL table with unique column values as keys

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I'm using Laravel's Eloquent ORM to retrieve data from MySQL database. I want to get all rows from the table where the unique values of a certain column of my choosing serves as the key, where each key holds an array of objects (each object is a row with the column value equal to that key). I am using Eloquent's Models

I tried using keyBy method from the Laravel docs, but that only gets one row in the new collection. I want all the rows in the new collection.

Example:

```
food table
name | type
apple | fruit
banana | fruit
asparagus | vegetable
broccoli | vegetable
```

I want to return

```
{"fruit": [{"name": "apple", "type": "fruit"}, {"name": "banana", "type": "fruit"}], "vegetable": [{"name": "asparagus", "type": "vegetable"}, {"name": "broccoli", "type": "vegetable"}]}
```

Instead, it's returning one object per key when I do

```
Food::all()->keyBy('type')
```

Is there a simple way of getting all the rows from the table and putting them into arrays depending on their key aka the column value that I specify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a groupBy on the Laravel Collection (not the Eloquent builder).

```
$collection = Food::all();
$grouped = $collection->groupBy('type');
```

This will give you separate collections for each type.